# BubbleSort and Selection Sort

Tags: java, sorting

So I'm trying to create Bubble and Selection sort and this is the code I have so far.

```
package club.westcs.javabasics;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class SortsRunner {

        public static void BubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> nums) {
            int n = nums.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                boolean swapped = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < n-1; j++) {
                    if (nums.get(j) > nums.get(j + 1)) {
                        int temp = nums.get(j);
                        nums.set(j, nums.get(j + 1));
                        nums.set(j + 1, temp);
                        swapped = true;
                    }
                }
                if (!swapped) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        public static void SelectionSort(ArrayList<Integer> nums) {
            int n = nums.size();              
            for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) 
            { 
                int min_idx = i; 
                for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) 
                    if (nums.get(j) < nums.get(min_idx)) 
                        min_idx = j; 

                int temp = nums.get(min_idx); 
                nums.set(j, nums.get(j+1)) = nums.set(i); 
                nums.set(i, min_idx) = temp; 
            } 
            }
        public static void printArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> nums) {
            for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(nums.get(i) + " ");
                }
            System.out.println();
            }
        public static ArrayList<Integer> makeRandomArrayList() {
            ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < (int)(Math.random() * 11) + 5; i++) {
                nums.add((int)(Math.random() * 100));
                }
            return nums;
            }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    printArrayList(makeRandomArrayList());

    }

}
```

My selection sort is erroring for  `nums.set(j, nums.get(j+1)) = nums.set(i);` and `nums.set(i, min_idx) = temp;` I want this portion of the code to swap the minimum element with the first element. I'm not sure how to do it correctly with the ArrayList stuff. Could someone give me some tips?

Comment: what is the error , may you share the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a compilation error because it is impossible to use '=' operator for **void** functions (such as `nums.set(j, nums.get(j+1))`). Setters are always void and you cannot assign smth to nothing!
The signature of ArrayList setter looks like:

```
public E set(int index, E element)
```

where first parameter is index of the array (0, 2, 3 ... N), second is a value  you want to set under this index.

By the way your selection sort looks strange.
Try this code:

```
public static void doSelectionSort(ArrayList<Integer> arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
            // find position of smallest num between (i + 1)th element and last element
            int pos = i;
            for (int j = i; j < arr.size(); j++) {
                if (arr.get(j) < arr.get(pos))
                    pos = j;
            }
            // Swap min (smallest num) to current position on array
            int min = arr.get(pos);
            arr.set(pos, arr.get(i));
            arr.set(i, min);
            printOut(i + 1, arr);
        }
    }
```